# How can I search all my Git stashes for a particular string?

Tags: git, git-stash

`git log --all -S <search-term>` searches the full history of all branches for changes that added or removed a given search term. Super powerful. Super cool.

But what if the change I am looking for was never committed to a branch, but was instead tucked away in a Git stash? Is there an easy way to search all of them for a particular string?

(I realise that stashes are a bad place to keep anything of importance for any length of time and that temporary branches are a better solution. I also realise that one's stash count should generally be kept pretty low. But best practices aside, I was just in a situation where I know I wrote some code months ago, but could not find it anywhere. Manually checking through my stashes to look for that code was a tedium I would prefer not to experience again.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git stash list` takes the same options as `git log`.
So you can do `git stash list -S <search term>`.

Comment: I feel I read the `git stash` manpage through at least twice, but I somehow never picked up on that part. Thanks!

Comment: @ParkerCoates: Git often hides important secrets in a single line in documentation. For instance, `git stash list` really runs `git reflog`, and `git reflog` really runs `git log`. :-)